# bootstrap 2.2.2 inline-help not show in middle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

what is the code problem? please see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5S5CB/77/).
 1. inline help not show in middle.
 2. when i scroll window, inline-help margin not true.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oCG5.jpg

```
        <form class="well  ">
        <div class="controls controls-row ">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="span5 ">
            <span class="help-inline">Please Enter Small Name.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span5" class="span5">
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span4" class="span4">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span1" class="span1">
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span3" class="span3">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span2" class="span2">
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span2" class="span2">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span3" class="span3">
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span1" class="span1">
            <input type="text" placeholder=".span4" class="span4">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              <form class="well  ">
                    <div class="controls controls-row ">
                      <input type="text" placeholder=".spanName">
                      <span class="help-inline">Inline help text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span5" class="span5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span4" class="span4">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span1" class="span1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span3" class="span3">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span2" class="span2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span2" class="span2">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span3" class="span3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span1" class="span1">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=".span4" class="span4">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

you are using a class in the input (class="span5" that is too big to have the inline help, so i advise you to have a regular size to the inline help works. 
i think this is what you want

Comment: thanx for your answer, but problem not solved. please see image in frist post. margin and vertical-align for inline-help not true.

Answer (score 1):

The `.help-inline` class only works properly within the context of a form with the `.form-horizontal` class attached and the `.control-group` containers which your form is missing. You can overcome this by aligning your `.help-inline` block yourself with some negative margins or properly setting up your form to use the `.form-horizontal` class along with the proper `.control-group` containers.

Comment: hi. thanx for your answer.  i changed it, please see
http://jsfiddle.net/5S5CB/85    it is correct ?